# How to display a Set property in a spring form?

Tags: java, spring, forms, properties, set

I am working on a Spring MVC web app and I'm trying to figure out a way to display a property of type Set that is part of the entity in question.  For the rest of the properties (String, boolean, int, etc) I can get away with the JSP file just using something like this to display them :

```
<li>
    <label for="active">Active :  </label>
    <form:checkbox path="active" id="active" disabled="true"/>
    <span><form:errors path="active" cssClass="error"/></span>
</li>
```

However, for a property of the entity which is a Set of other entities I cannot figure out how to display it.  I'm thinking of using some sort of sub-table but I fiddled with it a lot with no success. I tried searching google and can't quite find what I need.

Thanks!

*** New problem, but getting there! ***

My OrderedMed class has a property of type StrengthUnit and I'm able to display its name using the method in the comments below :

```
<li>
                            <label for="meds[${loop.index}].strengthUnit.name">Strength Units : </label> 
                            <form:input path="meds[${loop.index}].strengthUnit.name"/> 
                            <form:errors path="meds[${loop.index}].strengthUnit.name" cssClass="error" /> 
                        </li>
```

However, I need this to be a drop-down that the user can change.  My Med entity also has a property of type StrengthUnit and I'm able to accomplish what I want in its respective edit page by sending a list of all Strength Units from the controller and using the following code :

```
<select name="strengthUnit" path="strengthUnit.name" id="strengthUnit">
                                <option value="0" ${med.strengthUnit eq null ? 'selected' : ''}></option>
                                <c:forEach items="${strengthUnits}" var="strengthUnitSingle">
                                    <option value="${strengthUnitSingle.id}" ${med.strengthUnit.name eq strengthUnitSingle.name ? 'selected' : ''}>${strengthUnitSingle.name}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with this entity and I cannot seem to make it work using the method suggested in the comments.  I'm trying the below code :

```
<select name="strengthUnit" path="strengthUnit.name" id="strengthUnit">
                                <option value="0" ${meds[loop.index].strengthUnit eq null ? 'selected' : ''}></option>
                                <c:forEach items="${strengthUnits}" var="strengthUnitSingle">
                                    <option value="${strengthUnitSingle.id}" ${meds[loop.index].strengthUnit.name eq strengthUnitSingle.name ? 'selected' : ''}>${strengthUnitSingle.name}</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
```

Now i am getting this exception again :

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property '0' not found on type mdhis_webclient.entity.OrderedMed
```

I am using the same method to access the Set's index, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need a forEach loop with the varStatus, example:

```
<c:forEach var="yourVar" items="${yourList}" varStatus="loop" >
    <label for="yourVar[${loop.index}].something">Something ${loop.index + 1}</label>
    <form:input path="yourVar[${loop.index}].someting" cssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
    <form:errors path="yourVar[${loop.index}].something" cssClass="text-danger" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I gave it a shot and getting a NotReadablePropertyException.  Basically my entity is of type Order with a Set<OrderedMed> property.  Each OrderedMed has a Med property which in term has a genericName and that's what i want my form to display.  My modelAttribute for the form is "order".  Here's what i tried :

    <c:forEach var="orderedMed" items="${order.meds}" varStatus="loop" >

Comment: <label for="orderedMed[${loop.index}].med.genericName">${orderedMed.med.genericName} ${loop.index + 1}</label>
                            <form:input path="orderedMed[${loop.index}].med.genericName" cssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                            <form:errors path="orderedMed[${loop.index}].med.genericName" cssClass="error" />
                        </c:forEach>

Comment: sorry for the horrible code formatting in my comment

Comment: full Exception :
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'orderedMed[0]' of bean class [mdhis_webclient.entity.PRNOrder]: Bean property 'orderedMed[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: So I think I've got your model right so try the following: `<form:form modelAttribute="order">
    <c:forEach var="meds" items="${order.orderedMeds}" varStatus="loop" >
        <label for="orderedMeds[${loop.index}].genericName">${meds.genericName}</label>
        <form:input path="orderedMeds[${loop.index}].genericName" cssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
        <form:errors path="orderedMeds[${loop.index}].genericName" cssClass="text-danger" />
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>` Although the form model is order you still need to directly tell the forEach loop about it.

Comment: changed things slightly, i think this works!
<c:forEach var="orderedMed" items="${order.meds}" varStatus="loop" >
                            <label for="meds[${loop.index}].med.genericName">${orderedMed.med.genericName} ${loop.index + 1}</label>
                            <form:input path="meds[${loop.index}].med.genericName" cssClass="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                            <form:errors path="meds[${loop.index}].med.genericName" cssClass="error" />
                        </c:forEach>

Comment: new problem added to original post, getting there!

Comment: i added a new problem with another property.  Any insight on this one?  Thank you very much for your help so far!

Comment: With the second problem look into springs <form:options>, MkYong has some good examples, hopefully they may help: [link](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/) Just make sure you are using the correct model/property again.

Comment: Thank you for that, i'll definitely look into this.  However, the page loads fine if i don't try to have the correct strength unit selected based on what is in the OrderedMed property of my Order object.  Not sure why this works :

<form:input path="meds[${loop.index}].strengthUnit.name"/> 

and this doesn't :

<option value="0" ${meds[loop.index].strengthUnit eq null ? 'selected' : ''}></option>

I'm sure it's a syntax issue as for the working part i am referring to the index from HTML and for the non-working part i am referring to it from within JQuery code.

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the exception it seems that it's looking for a property of zero on the OrderedMed object and not the value of strengthUnit so I think your mapping is incorrect. Using the spring form version of the select and options means you don't have to worry about for loops here, but if you do use it remove the varStatus for this particular one. [Sorry just seen you have.]

Comment: in looking at the form:select tags it looks like the path attribute might do exactly what i need without needing the piece of code that doesn't work.  I will give it a shot.

Comment: You sir are awesome, thank you VERY much.  I will post the working code in a new answer!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of my question, this is what i needed!  I just needed a toString() method to my StrengthUnit entity (they should all have one anyway!)

```
<form:select name="strengthUnit" path="meds[${loop.index}].strengthUnit.name" id="strengthUnit">
    <form:option value="0" label=""></form:option>
    <form:options items="${strengthUnits}" />
</form:select>
```